# Selecting a Join in sqlalchemy gives too many rows

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a compound SQL query that builds a table from a join I have previously performed. (Using SqlAlchemy (Core part) with python3 and Postgresql 9.4)

I include here the relevant part of my python3 code. I first create "in_uuid_set" using a select with a group_by. Then I join "in_uuid_set" with "in_off_messages" to get "jn_in".
Finally, I try to build a new table "incoming" from "jn_in" by selecting and generating the wanted columns:

```
in_uuid_set = \
    sa.select([in_off_messages.c.src_uuid.label('remote_uuid')])\
    .select_from(in_off_messages)\
    .where(in_off_messages.c.dst_uuid == local_uuid)\
    .group_by(in_off_messages.c.src_uuid)\
    .alias()


jn_in = in_uuid_set.join(in_off_messages,\
    and_(\
        in_off_messages.c.src_uuid == in_uuid_set.c.remote_uuid,\
        in_off_messages.c.dst_uuid == local_uuid,\
        ))\
    .alias()


incoming = sa.select([\
    in_off_messages.c.msg_uuid.label('msg_uuid'),\
    in_uuid_set.c.remote_uuid.label('remote_uuid'),\
    in_off_messages.c.msg_type.label('msg_type'),\
    in_off_messages.c.date_sent.label('date_sent'),\
    in_off_messages.c.content.label('content'),\
    in_off_messages.c.was_read.label('was_read'),\
    true().label('is_incoming')]
    )\
    .select_from(jn_in)
```

Surprisingly, I get that "incoming" has more rows than "jn_in". "incoming" has 12 rows, while "jn_in" has only 2 rows. I expect that "incoming" will have the same amount of rows (2) as "jn_in".

I also include here the SQL output the SqlAlchemy generates for "incoming":

```
SELECT in_off_messages.msg_uuid  AS msg_uuid,
       anon_1.remote_uuid        AS remote_uuid,
       in_off_messages.msg_type  AS msg_type,
       in_off_messages.date_sent AS date_sent,
       in_off_messages.content   AS content,
       in_off_messages.was_read  AS was_read,
       1                         AS is_incoming
FROM   in_off_messages,
       (SELECT in_off_messages.src_uuid AS remote_uuid
        FROM   in_off_messages
        WHERE  in_off_messages.dst_uuid = :dst_uuid_1
        GROUP  BY in_off_messages.src_uuid) AS anon_1,
       (SELECT anon_1.remote_uuid            AS anon_1_remote_uuid,
               in_off_messages.msg_uuid      AS in_off_messages_msg_uuid,
               in_off_messages.orig_src_uuid AS in_off_messages_orig_src_uuid,
               in_off_messages.src_uuid      AS in_off_messages_src_uuid,
               in_off_messages.dst_uuid      AS in_off_messages_dst_uuid,
               in_off_messages.msg_type      AS in_off_messages_msg_type,
               in_off_messages.date_sent     AS in_off_messages_date_sent,
               in_off_messages.content       AS in_off_messages_content,
               in_off_messages.was_read      AS in_off_messages_was_read
        FROM   (SELECT in_off_messages.src_uuid AS remote_uuid
                FROM   in_off_messages
                WHERE  in_off_messages.dst_uuid = :dst_uuid_1
                GROUP  BY in_off_messages.src_uuid) AS anon_1
               JOIN in_off_messages
                 ON in_off_messages.src_uuid = anon_1.remote_uuid
                    AND in_off_messages.dst_uuid = :dst_uuid_2) AS anon_2
```

Something doesn't look right for me with this SQL output, mostly because I see GROUP BY too many times. I would have expected it to show up about once, but it seems like it shows up twice here.

My guesses is that somehow some braces went out of place (In the generated SQL). I also suspect that I did something wrong with the alias() thing, though I'm not sure about it.

What should I do to get the wanted result (Same amount of rows for "jn_in" and "incoming")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the code for a while, I found a way to fix it.
The answer was eventually related to the alias().
In order to make this work, the second alias() (Of jn_in) should be omitted, like this:

```
in_uuid_set = \
    sa.select([in_off_messages.c.src_uuid.label('remote_uuid')])\
    .select_from(in_off_messages)\
    .where(in_off_messages.c.dst_uuid == local_uuid)\
    .group_by(in_off_messages.c.src_uuid)\
    .alias()


jn_in = in_uuid_set.join(in_off_messages,\
    and_(\
        in_off_messages.c.src_uuid == in_uuid_set.c.remote_uuid,\
        in_off_messages.c.dst_uuid == local_uuid,\
        ))
# <<< The alias() is gone >>>



incoming = sa.select([\
    in_off_messages.c.msg_uuid.label('msg_uuid'),\
    in_uuid_set.c.remote_uuid.label('remote_uuid'),\
    in_off_messages.c.msg_type.label('msg_type'),\
    in_off_messages.c.date_sent.label('date_sent'),\
    in_off_messages.c.content.label('content'),\
    in_off_messages.c.was_read.label('was_read'),\
    true().label('is_incoming')]
    )\
    .select_from(jn_in)
```

It seems, however, that the first alias() (of in_uuid_set) can not be ommited. If I try to omit it, I get this error message:

```
E               subquery in FROM must have an alias
E               LINE 2: FROM (SELECT in_off_messages.src_uuid AS remote_uuid 
E                            ^
E               HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

As a generalization of this, probably if you have a select that you want to put as a clause somewhere else, then you want to alias() it, however if you have a join that you want to put as a clause, you should not alias() it.

For the sake of completeness, I include here the resulting SQL of the new code:

```
SELECT in_off_messages.msg_uuid  AS msg_uuid,
       anon_1.remote_uuid        AS remote_uuid,
       in_off_messages.msg_type  AS msg_type,
       in_off_messages.date_sent AS date_sent,
       in_off_messages.content   AS content,
       in_off_messages.was_read  AS was_read,
       1                         AS is_incoming
FROM   (SELECT in_off_messages.src_uuid AS remote_uuid
        FROM   in_off_messages
        WHERE  in_off_messages.dst_uuid = :dst_uuid_1
        GROUP  BY in_off_messages.src_uuid) AS anon_1
       JOIN in_off_messages
         ON in_off_messages.src_uuid = anon_1.remote_uuid
            AND in_off_messages.dst_uuid = :dst_uuid_2
```

Much shorter than the one at the question.